# Removing last portion of PHP Manual Trigger Error Message

Tags: php, triggers

I am trying to trigger a warning or error message when someone submits a contact form containing a keyword from a list of words. So far, the error works, but I would like for the custom message to not include the following "in /home/austincyberknife/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Custom_Caldera_Spam_Filter.php_/Custom_Caldera_Spam_Filter.php on line 83" at the end of the message. Is that possible? The error is to prompt the user to resubmit their contact form without that term and seeing where the error is coming from is unnecessary.

```php
    if( $block ){
        //Error Message
        trigger_error("WARNING: INVALID COMMENT. PLEASE REMOVE COMMENT AND HIT SUBMIT.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }else{
        //Email address that gets the other messages
        $mailer[ 'recipients' ] = array( 'email@email.com'  );

    }

    return $mailer;
```

EDIT - I ended up adding this to the functions.php file and it appears to be working.

```php
/************************************************************/
/* Contact Spam Error */
/************************************************************/
// error handler function
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>WARNING:</b> $errstr<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Comment: what is the full error message?

Comment: Take a look at the user notes in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) and you'll notice that a user error handler is usually used in conjunction with it to create a customized message. Without a user error handler you will get the default in the format you are seeing.

Comment: Fatal Error: WARNING: INVALID COMMENT. PLEASE REMOVE COMMENT AND HIT SUBMIT. in /home/austincyberknife/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Custom_Caldera_Spam_Filter.php_/Custom_Caldera_Spam_Filter.php on line 83

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but does that mean I need to add a error handler to my functions file? This is the first time I've really dug into PHP.

Comment: I think I got it figured out. I added the following as a function and it appears to be working. David, do you mind double checking this for any issues?